# Find same list elements of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Example: I have two 2D lists (each list has no duplicate elements):

```
l1 = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}};
l2 = {{1, 1}, {3, 3}, {5, 5}};
```

How can I create a new list which consists of elements that are same in both lists?

The result should be:

```
l={{1, 1}, {3, 3}};
```

Comment: `Intersection[l1,l2]`?